# Docker - pip install all requirements.txt files in shared volume on docker.compose up

Tags: docker, pip, docker-compose, docker-volume

I am trying to use docker-compose to share python modules with other containers ensuring these containers all have 100% of the requirements.txt files pip installed.

I have been able to use volumes to share the the shared python modules with the other containers (at /src/shared-modules). However I'm struggling to automate the 'pip installing' of all the requirements.txt files found within /src/shared-modules.

The Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM python:3.6.5

COPY . /src

**#Run pip install on all found requirements.txt files in the container**
RUN for req in `find . -name requirements.txt -type f`; do pip install --trusted-host pypi.org -r $req; done

WORKDIR /src
```

This works for everything in the host folder copied to the container but doesn't work for anything in the /src/shared-modules folders. Maybe they don't exist yet at the time the pip install command is run in the dockerfile or maybe they haven't been linked to the source shared-modules container yet?

The docker-compose.yaml looks like this:

```
  db:
    image: tutum/mongodb

  shared-modules:
    build: ./shared-modules
    volumes:
      - "shared-modules:/src/shared-modules"

  web:
    build: ./django-site
    entrypoint: "python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - "shared-modules:/src/shared-modules"


volumes:
  shared-modules:
```

I have tried to add the pip install to the entrypoint + command commands in the docker-compose-yaml file which looks like this:

```
  web:
    build: ./django-site
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    command: "for req in `find /src/shared-modules -name requirements.txt -type f`; do pip install --trusted-host pypi.org -r $req; done && python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    volumes:
      - "shared-modules:/src/shared-modules"
```

I hoped that this would run the command on an already created container, already linked to the shared-modules container but the requriemtns.txt files of the /src/shared-modules were not installed on docker-compose up.

The

> for req in `find . -name requirements.txt -type f`; do pip install
>   --trusted-host pypi.org -r $req; done

command works but only if I attach to the running container after its creation  and manually do it. I would really like to automate that as part of the docker-compose up process.

**How can I execute a bash command on a container after the volume is assigned as part of the docker-compose up process?**

**Is there a better way to do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get your general approach here.
If you want to make sure that all containers have all the python packages installed just install them 'normally' in the Dockerfile by running
`pip install -r requirements.txt`
And perhaps think about a base Dockerfile which all the containers share.
This could include all the installations.

Your volume approach looks very hacky. Might not be worth to make it work.

Comment: Thanks Saskia - I appreciate the perspective.Could you elaborate a bit on how this is implemented?

Comment: After a bit of trial and error I now have a base image which includes all the shared modules.  It is a much nicer solution - thanks for the hint 353.

Answer (score 0):

Even tho Docker's documentation has some examples about the Dockerfile-approach that Saskia mentioned about, I don't think there's anything wrong about your original approach. The Dockerfile-approach may be simple for small projects, but when building bigger kind of infrastructure that contains multiple services, using volume mounts is more explicit and readable. But this of course depends on use case.

I like to do multiple .yml files, for example build.yml where I may have the same services I have in the main docker-compose.yml. Those services are going to install the requirements for themselves, or what ever building logic they need to do. I can use the build.yml by running `docker-compose -f build.yml up`, then grab a cup of coffee and watch how the whole system is building up simultaneously. After that the `docker-compose up` should work since the requirements are already installed.